# Show gradient image over another image with css and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show gradient image over another image but the gradient image is not shown over the another image. My code is as follows:

```
<style>
.splash-gradient
{
background-image: url('images/gradient.png');
background-position: left;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
float: right;
height: 300px;
width: 362px;
}
</style>
<div class="col-md-6"> <img src="images1.jpg" /></div>

 <div id="gradient-background" class="splash-gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid to use empty markup only for styling purpose. You could just add a class to the existant markup

```
<div class="col-md-6 splash-gradient"> 
  <img src="images1.jpg" />
</div>
```

and then use this style:

```
.splash-gradient {
    position: relative;
}

.splash-gradient:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('images/gradient.png') top left repeat-y;
    height: 300px;
    width: 362px;   
}
```

the gradient is inserted on the `:before` pseudoelement and since is in `position: absolute` it overlaps the image (of course feel free to adjust width and height)

Comment: Does this not assume that image completely fills the div? Otherwise there would be a gradient over more than the image. I think it's the optimal answer...but...

Comment: right, but he can easily adjust height and/or width of the psuedoelement. Since there'no an available example to see, this is just a suggestion

Comment: Good point...BTW, would you hard code `px` values, I tend to set width and height as 100%